# Java: Calling repaint() in static context (Or how to avoid it)

Tags: java, swing, awt

I am working on a simple app Java/Swing, which involves having the user click on a box and drag it around. I am having troubles with understanding how the repaint method can be used. I created this example of the problem, in which a square is drawn and then on mousePressed it gets the x cordinates of the click, and displaces the original drawing by however much the pointer is moved.

I have read the commonly referred guides on drawing in Swing, but I haven't seen any answers to the question on how to write a program that incorporates both mouseMotion and mouseListener (which as far as I can tell means that the mouseListener must be implemented as its own class, as opposed to the common solution of incorporating it into the custom JPanel class) and also calls `repaint()` based on mouse actions.

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.event.MouseInputAdapter;


class drawTest extends JPanel {
    static int xpos_square = 200; 
    static int ypos_square = 200; 
    int width = 100;  
    int height = 100;

    static int x_init;
    static int y_init;

    public drawTest(){
        addMouseListener(new mouseListener());
        addMouseMotionListener(new mouseListener());
        setBackground(Color.BLACK); 
    }

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        drawSquare(g);
    }

    public void drawSquare(Graphics g){
        g.setColor(Color.GREEN);
        g.fillRect(xpos_square, ypos_square, height, width);            
    }   

    public static void moveShape(int x, int y){
        xpos_square += x-x_init;
        ypos_square += y-y_init;
        repaint();
    }
    public static void getChord(int x, int y){
        x_init = x;
        y_init = y;     
    }
}   

class mouseListener extends MouseInputAdapter{

    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e){     
        drawTest.getChord(e.getX(),e.getY());
    }   

    public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e){
        drawTest.moveShape(e.getX(),e.getY());
    }       
}

public class myTest {

    JFrame myFrame = new JFrame();
    JPanel myDrawing = new drawTest();

    public myTest () {
        myFrame.add(myDrawing);
        myFrame.setSize(500,500);
        myFrame.setVisible(true);
        myFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }   

    public static void main(String []args){
        new myTest(); 
    }   
}
```

The issue is of course that `repaint()` cannot be called in a static context. However, I don't see how I can avoid this, since if I want the position to smoothly update, it has to be called via the mouseDragged method.

How else could I use the `repaint()` method to redraw based on mouse movements?

Comment: There are a number of ways to approach this problem, which all should have been sorted when you were learning Java OOP concepts in command line apps.

Comment: Please also abide by the naming guidelines for Java that include classes starting with a capital letter (like `MyTest` over `myTest` etc.)

Answer (score 1):

So I figured out a way around it, using anonymous methods in addMouseListener. This bypasses the need for static methods in the call to repaint. If anyone else has a similar question, maybe they will find it helpful.

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.event.MouseInputAdapter;


class DrawTest extends JPanel {
    static int xpos_square = 200; 
    static int ypos_square = 200; 
    int width = 100;  
    int height = 100;

    static int x_init;
    static int y_init;

    public DrawTest(){
        addMouseListener(new mouseListener(){   public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e){     
            getClick(e.getX(),e.getY());
        }});
        addMouseMotionListener(new mouseListener(){ public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e){
            moveShape(e.getX(),e.getY());   
        }});
        setBackground(Color.BLACK); 
    }

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        drawSquare(g);
    }

    public void drawSquare(Graphics g){
        g.setColor(Color.GREEN);
        g.fillRect(xpos_square, ypos_square, height, width);            
    }   

    public void moveShape(int x, int y){
        if((x >= xpos_square)&&(x <= xpos_square + width)&&(y >= ypos_square)&&(y <= ypos_square + height)){
            xpos_square += x-x_init;
            ypos_square += y-y_init;
            x_init = x;
            y_init = y; 
            repaint();
        }
    }
    public void getClick(int x, int y){
        x_init = x;
        y_init = y;     
    }
}

public class MyTest {

    JFrame myFrame = new JFrame();
    JPanel myDrawing = new DrawTest();

    public MyTest () {
        myFrame.add(myDrawing);
        myFrame.setSize(500,500);
        myFrame.setVisible(true);
        myFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }   

    public static void main(String []args){
        new MyTest(); 
    }   
}
```

Comment: Plus one on not only figuring out one way to do this, but for including the solution as an answer.